# therubyracer installation in git bash

Tags: ruby, therubyracer

i have installed the bundle in git bash , it said that i have to install therubyracer 0.11.4.
I have installed it so many times , but it doesn't run in my windows 7 .
How to resolve this problem?

```
$ gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.4'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... no
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
        --with-pthreadlib
        --without-pthreadlib
        --enable-debug
        --disable-debug
        --with-v8-dir
        --without-v8-dir
        --with-v8-include
        --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
        --with-v8-lib
        --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/l
ocation.rb:50:in `configure': You have chosen to use the version of V8 found on
your system (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem. However,
it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of
v8 that is compatible with 3.11.8.17 installed. You may
need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard
location

thanks,
The Mgmt

        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.1
7/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
        from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
.1/gems/therubyracer-0.11.4 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyra
cer-0.11.4/ext/v8/gem_make.out
```

Comment: "i have installed the bundle in git bash": Don't you think that's a little abrupt for a first sentence?  What OS are you using, what are you trying to create, and what pieces of software have you installed already?  What is the content of your Gemfile?  Were you able to find mkmf.log and check it?

Comment: Hallo David, 
That was actually little abrupt for a first a first sentence XD.
My OS : Windows 7.
I am actually working with my friends with Github, but 2 days before ,one of my friend has inputed Therubyracer and pushed it to Github.
After that i was trying to run the program as normally and then i inputed for the first step in Gitbash :
1. Find my project directory (cd ....)
2. active the with "rake db:migrate" , but in the end it said that :
     -[31mCould not find therubyracer-0.11.4 in any of the  sources←[0m
     -[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m

Comment: BTW, i have installed Sublime text 2, git bash , git hub and git shell.

My GEMFILE CONTENT: 

`gem 'rails', '3.2.13'`    
`gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'`      
`gem 'carrierwave'`   
`gem 'geocoder'   
gem 'gmaps4rails'   
gem 'nested_form'    
gem 'jquery-rails'    
group :assets do    
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'    
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'    
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'   
gem "less-rails"   
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'    
end   
group :test do    
  gem 'factory_girl', '~> 4.2.0'     
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.1.0'    
end      `

Comment: `group :development, :test do   
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.13.1'   
  gem 'sqlite3'    
  gem 'better_errors'    
  gem 'binding_of_caller'    
  gem 'pry'    
end    
group :production do     
  gem 'pg'    
end    
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'         
 `

Comment: BTW, i dont know , how to locate mkmf.log ...